# Is there a formula for the constants of the Taylor Series of the inverse of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion, inverse-function

Given a function $f$ and a point $x_0$, one should be able to find the Taylor Series of the inverse of $f$ about $f(x_0)$, using the derivatives of $f$.
$$
f^{-1}(y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (y-f(x_0))^n
$$
So far, through some tedious (and kind of sketchy) working out, I have found the following:
$$
\begin{align}
a_0 &= x_0\\
a_1 &= \frac1{f'(x_0)}\\
a_2 &= \frac{f''(x_0)}{2f'(x_0)^3}\\
a_3 &= \frac{3f''\left(x_{0}\right)^{2}-f'\left(x_{0}\right)f'''\left(x_{0}\right)}{6f'\left(x_{0}\right)^{5}}\\
a_4 &= \frac{10f'\left(x_{0}\right)f''\left(x_{0}\right)f'''\left(x_{0}\right)-15f''\left(x_{0}\right)^{3}-f'\left(x_{0}\right)^{2}f''''\left(x_{0}\right)}{24f'\left(x_{0}\right)^{7}}
\end{align}
$$
Obviously, the complexity of each constant seems to grow exponentially, and I am afraid to even try to find $a_5$ because it might take all day. I don't see any obvious patterns, other than that the power in the denominator increases by $2$ each time, and that the constant in the denominator is given by $n!$.

Is there a formula for these constants?

Comment: It's somewhat possible, but difficult. See [this short paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.890.2170&rep=rep1&type=pdf#:~:text=A%20Taylor%20power%20series%20is,given%20in%20an%20implicit%20form.&text=This%20formula%20is%20further%20applied,the%20resulting%20series%20is%20evaluated.) for details.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: We must have type it at the same time

Comment: Connected : the formulas you find in the paragraph "Related transformations / Inversion" of  https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/7/

Comment: See this nice answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3317234 mentionning the **Lagrange-Bührmann inversion formulas**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constants that I have am trying to find can be found by using the [Lagrange–Bürmann formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem), as people have helpfully brought up in the comments.
$$
a_n = \lim_{w\to x_0} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left[\left( \frac{w-x_0}{f(w)-f(x_0)} \right)^n\right].
$$
It looks like this is the most compact general form these constants can take.